# Javascript error:Unable to get property 'cells' of undefined or null reference

Tags: javascript

My website page cannot load the body content. When debug it stop when it calling the javascript to load the body. The error I get is:
Unable to get property 'cells' of undefined or null reference

which at this line of code:

```
l.cellWidth=l.targetRect.width/l.rows[0].cells.length;
```

Can anyone help me with this

Comment: You need to share more context to the problem...

Comment: You cannot read properties or execute methods on objects that are null or undefined. In your case it's `l`. What is `l` in your code? Paste in more code.

Comment: Where is your script - in the head or the body of the page? Are you using the onload function to wait until the page has actually been loaded? Really need more information to be able to help you.